# xgboost module is not recognized

Tags: python, machine-learning, importerror, xgboost, xgbclassifier

Though there is another question on the same issue, the solution stated there does not work for me. Hence this is not a duplicate or re-post. And I am posting my issue and implementation specifics here.

I am currently working on PyCharm on a simple ML prediction task where I'd like to use xgboost. I have performed the following so far.

- cd into the virtual environment folder

  `$ cd My_Project`
- Activate the venv

  `source myproject/bin/activate`
- pip install xgboost

  `$ sudo pip install xgboost`
- Upgrade installation

  `$ sudo pip install --upgrade xgboost`

I also added the xgboost module to the project interpreter in pycharm with Python 3.6.

[image]

The python file that I'm trying to run has the following imports.

```
from numpy import loadtxt
from xgboost import XGBClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
```

But as I run the script, I get this error.

> from xgboost import XGBClassifier
>   ImportError: No module named 'xgboost'

**Specifications**

- Ubuntu 16.04
- PyCharm
- Python 3.6
- File name : `classifxg.py` (NOT `xgboost.py` - *which is said to cause this **No module error** according to the other question on stackoverflow*)

Any help in this regard will be much appreciated.

Comment: You should never use sudo with pip, its probably not the root of the problem, but it introduces other issues.

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro Thanks for the suggestion Mat.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, but found out my file was also named `xgboost.py`, so it was trying to import the Classifier from my own file not the dependency.